# Multiple databases of Teradata and SAS in UNIX

Tags: sql, unix, sas, teradata

I would like to know how to query multiple databases of the same server of Teradata in SAS (unix). I can do it for one database but there are few different databases involved in my queries. The only related article was [SAS connection to Teradata Database using Teradata ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237581/sas-connection-to-teradata-database-using-teradata-odbc) but could not get the right answer. Could you please share syntax/snippet. Any comment is appreciated.
Thanks!

Jas

Edits:

Please see the below script, I want to do something like this.

```
libname lib 'mylibraryPath\';

proc sql;
connect to teradata  (user="userid" password="pwaaaowrd" mode=teradata  database=DB1   database=DB2   database=DB3   tdpid="MyServer");
execute (
create volatile table lib.tab1 as 
(

Select statements and several joins of different tables from different databases (server is same)
)
WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX (abcd)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
)
By Teradata;
execute (commit work) by Teradata;
disconnect from teradata;
quit;
```

Comment: Qualifying your table names like **select * from databasename.tablename** should work

Comment: What you're doing appears to be correct.  What is the problem you're facing?  I think you can get rid of those "database=" parameters in your "connect" statement and just pre-qualify the table names with the database names as dnoeth suggests.

Comment: Can you give a very specific example including an example SELECT statement?  That will help.

Answer (score 1):

as written by Chris in the Question you linked you could use a so called implicit pass-through defining a libname for every Teradata db you need to point to:

```
libname db1 teradata user=xxx1 password=yyy1 database=zzz1;
libname db2 teradata user=xxx2 password=yyy2 database=zzz2;
```

Then you can use these inside Data steps or SQL queries as if they were standard SAS libraries:

```
data join;
    merge db1.table1 db2.table2;
    by id;
run;
```

or

```
proc sql;
    select *
    from db1.table1 t1
    left join db2.table2 t2
        on t1.id=t2.id;
quit;
```