# Using ODBC in SAS to Access Teradata

Tags: sas, odbc, teradata

I am thinking of using **SAS** and would like to know:

Is it possible to use **ODBC** to access a **Teradata** database in **SAS**?

I know that accessing **MS Access** using **ODBC** in **SAS** is possible, and accessing **Teradata** with **Excel VBA** using **ODBC** is possible, but I can not find anything for **SAS** with **Teradata** and **ODBC**.

Comment: check this link, might be useful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237581/sas-connection-to-teradata-database-using-teradata-odbc

Comment: @Kiran +1 Thanks for the link, it looks like it can be done, not sure why I had not found it.

Comment: You don't need odbc for this, use the libname expression: libname yoursource teradata server=&server database=&database user=&USER password=&PASS mode=teradata;

Answer (score 1):

connecting to Teradata by connect statement can be done by connect statement as shown below.

```
  proc sql ;
  connect to teradata (server=server user=user pw=pw );
  create table work.emp as
  (select *
 from connection to teradata
 (select a.*,
  row_number()over(partition by deptno order by hiredate) as rn from
 prod_targetdb.customer_table a
 ));
disconnect from teradata;
quit;
```

looks like connect to ODBC will also work but looks like it has more limitations, 
like fastload capability and others, please look into the page 24 in the link given below

https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ake/courses/cs590w/SASACCESS.pdf